# Changing image of rating bar in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, ratingbar

i want to use custom ratingbar icons for each rating like below  image. I want user to select rating between 1 to 10 . [image]

Now im trying with the code below:

```
        <com.whinc.widget.ratingbar.RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBars"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            app:rb_max_count="10"
            app:rb_count="1"
            app:rb_empty="@drawable/empty"
            app:rb_fill="@drawable/fill"
            app:rb_space="20dp"
            app:rb_click_rating="true"
            app:rb_touch_rating="true"/>
```

But i can only change full image not individual .please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Use    `android:stepSize="0.1"`    &   `android:numStars="10"` like below:

```
  <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:numStars="10"
                android:stepSize="0.1"
                android:isIndicator="true" />
```

Comment: hai thanks for your reply. currently i am using star for background image. i want to show different image for each rating

Comment: Ok then trying change the step size. Maybe it helps.